# Import error while running python script using script module in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Directory Structure:

```
    |-- Script
    |   |-- Name.py
    |   |-- Name.pyc
    |   |-- Test.py
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- __pycache__
    |       `-- Name.cpython-36.pyc
    |-- SimplePlaybook.yml
    |-- ansible.cfg
    |-- ansible_log.log
    |-- hosts
```

Script Folder:

Name.py

```
    student_name = "Jhon Doe"
```

Test.py

```
    import Name
        
    print("My Name is %s \n" % Name.student_name)
        
    sys.exit({"rc": 0, "changed": True})
```

Playbook:

```
---

-

  hosts: HOST
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:

    - name: Print Gathered Facts
      debug:
        var: hostvars

    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ playbook_dir }}"

    - name: Run Test Script
      script: "{{ playbook_dir }}/Script/Test.py"
      register: result
      args:
        executable: python3

    - debug:
        var: result

...
```

I am getting an import error.

**Issue:**

import error of Name.py, module not found

**Debug Observation:**

when ansible run the `Test.py` file it runs from the path like below location
`ansible/tmp/ansible-xxxx`
I tried to add that path in python path but still got an import error of Name.py

need inputs here to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you spell everything correctly.  The error says “Nmae.py”, but the module is named “Name.py”.

Comment: spell corrected , Thank you @dan_linder